# mysql query in shellscript

Tags: mysql, shell

I need to create a database in Shell-Script and insert into database considering the following scenario.
My question is "How to generate random numbers as marks for each registration numbers and insert to database" ?

Scenario :
1) Create a table called "students" (reg_id, subject, marks) Select the proper data types and lengths. Note: if there exist a students table drop it first.
2) Generate and insert records to the table according to the following criteria.
      a. Student reg_id should be like "idx". "x" should be start from 1. Ex: id1, id2..... id138
      b. Every student should have marks only for 8 subjects. (Optional subjects  : Art, Computer, literature)
      c. The maximum number of records should be able to change using a parameter.
      d. The subject  marks can be vary from 0 to 100.

Here is the code i wrote :

```
#!/bin/bash

NoOfSubjects=8

# create students table
mysql -u root school << EOF
drop table students;
create table students (reg_id varchar (10) not null, subject varchar(20), marks int);
EOF

echo "Enter number of students"
read NoOfStudents

# get list of subjects from teachers table
results=`mysql -u root school -e "select subject from teachers;"` 
#get results into array
read -r -a arr <<< ${results}

# get marks from terminal
studentCount=1
subjectCount=1
count=1
while [ ${studentCount} -le ${NoOfStudents} ]
do
    echo "Enter marks for student :" ${studentCount} " with spaces"
        #marks=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
        #echo $marks
        #count=`expr ${count} + 1`
    read marks
    student_id="id"${studentCount}

    # enter to db
    for input in ${marks}
    do
        if [ ${input} -ge 0 ] && [ ${input} -le 100 ]
        then
            `mysql -u root school -e "insert into students(reg_id, subject, marks) values ('${student_id}','${arr[$subjectCount]}',${input})"`
            subjectCount=`expr ${subjectCount} + 1`
        else
            echo "Invalid marks: " ${input}
        fi
    done

    studentCount=`expr ${studentCount} + 1`
    subjectCount=1
done
```

Comment: What's the problem? I was going to answer that you can use `$RANDOM` to get random numbers in shell, but the commented-out code indicates that you already know that.

Comment: yeah but the {$RANDOM} doesn't create random numbers for the given scenario.. i need to get what is really wrong with the code??

Comment: `marks=$((RANDOM % 100))` works for me

Comment: it expect me to press "enter key" each time and the random values doesn't get added to database. but when i enter manually it gets added !

Comment: When you use the random assignment, don't you take out `read marks`?

Comment: the loop structure was wrong i guess.. now i corrected and its working ! thnx :)